# Microsoft Active Directory Admin - Discriminate usable USB Disk devices

Tags: windows, usb, active-directory, group-policy, domain

good morning, I have been trying for a while through policy management or other microsoft media to restrict the use of USB removable disks. I know that through Active Direcory I can enable and disable indisciminately or discriminating users, usb ports. But I would also like to have a management of which storage device my users can use (i.e., I want them to use only those that my office provides them with).

So far I have only found external programs that allow me to perform this kind of control, example: manageengine device control pro, and others.

So I pose the question: Is it possible to discriminate the usb storage devices that the EndPoints I manage can use? Without, however, blocking the installation of all devices example mice, keyboards, and others?

Comment: Active Directory has nothing to do with this. AD can deploy a setting if you already know what it is. It isn't a magic hat to do actual IT work.